# WordPress Custom Post Type Admin UI

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a way to change the admin UI (on a custom post type) from the big WYSIWYG text area, to individual inputs that deal with the custom post type?

For example, if I have a custom post type of "Charity", I'll want a charity name, charity website, charity email, etc. Where in the Codex (or on Google) would I look for something like that? I haven't been able to find it yet.

I figure I can hack WP to do this much easier than building my own CMS, so that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware of **[Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)** in WordPress.Using Custom fields you can do that.

There is plugin also available for custom fileds

**[Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/)**

Thanks